# ListView entre fragments

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragment, android-asynctask

agradeceré su guía respecto a esto :

Tengo 2 fragments :

-fragment 1 (principal) : Contiene un ListView y un botón que lleva al fragment 2

-fragment 2 : Contiene un EditText y un botón para volver al fragment 1

Al pinchar en el boton del fragment 1 se abre el fragment 2, aquí ingreso un valor y pincho el boton. Al pinchar el boton necesito llevar el valor del EditText al ListView del fragment 1 e ir agregando valores a la lista de ese modo.

El problema es que solo puedo agregar un valor, al agregar el segundo se pierde el item anterior.

¿Como puedo mantener el estado del fragment 1 sin perder datos?

Estoy con android studio y java.

Agradeceré su guía, muchas gracias.

He editado esta pregunta con el código que he avanzado :

Primero quiero solo enviar lo de un EditText(dosFragment) hacia un textView(unoFragment) pero no me muestra el unoFragment, al presionar el botón de enviar(dosFragment) se queda ahí.

---

MainActivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements 
dosFragment.OnMessageSendListener{

unoFragment unoFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    if(findViewById(R.id.frame_container)!= null){
        if(savedInstanceState!=null){
            return;
        }
        unoFragment = new unoFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.frame_container, unoFragment, "uno_fragment").commit();
    }
}

@Override
public void onMessageSend(String message) {
    unoFragment unoFragment = (unoFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("uno_fragment");

    if(unoFragment != null){
        unoFragment.updateTextView(message);
        Log.e("FRAGMENT","ENTRO AL FRAGMENT YA CREADO");
    }else{

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(unoFragment.ARG_MESSAGE, message);
        unoFragment.setArguments(args);
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, unoFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
}
```

unoFragment :

```
public class unoFragment extends Fragment {
final static String ARG_MESSAGE = "message";

Button btnFragment2;
TextView txtRecibido;
String mCurrentPosition = "";

public unoFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if(savedInstanceState != null){
        mCurrentPosition = savedInstanceState.getString(ARG_MESSAGE);
    }
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_uno, container, false);

    txtRecibido = v.findViewById(R.id.txtRecibido);

    btnFragment2 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnFragment2);
    btnFragment2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dosFragment dosFragment=new dosFragment();

            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container,dosFragment)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
        }
    });

    return v;
}

public void updateTextView(String message){
    txtRecibido.setText(message);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    Bundle args = getArguments();
    if (args != null) {
        // Set article based on argument passed in
        updateTextView(args.getString(ARG_MESSAGE));
    }else if(mCurrentPosition != ""){
        updateTextView(mCurrentPosition);
    }
}

public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString(ARG_MESSAGE, mCurrentPosition);
}
}
```

---

dosFragment :

```
public class dosFragment extends Fragment {
Button btnDevolver;
EditText edtItemLista;

OnMessageSendListener messageSendListener;

public interface OnMessageSendListener{
     public void onMessageSend(String message);
}

public dosFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dos, container, false);

    btnDevolver = v.findViewById(R.id.btnDevolver);
    edtItemLista = v.findViewById(R.id.edtItemLista);

    btnDevolver.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String message = edtItemLista.getText().toString();
            messageSendListener.onMessageSend(message);
        }
    });
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

    Activity activity = (Activity) context;
    try {
        messageSendListener = (OnMessageSendListener) activity;
    }
    catch (ClassCastException e){
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()+ " necesita implementar onMessageSend...");
    }
}

}
```

---

Comment: Hola, por favor tómate un momento y lee esta página https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Deberías añadir el código que has intentado para poder responderte mejor.

Comment: Para comunicar un fragment con otro debes pasar por tu actividad contenedora por medio de un callback que mande la información a su actividad y esta mande al otro fragment al reemplazarlo en la transacción. Este link te ayudara.... https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno para lograr el objetivo puedes intentar lo siguiente:
Dado que tienes un listview, para mostrar los items debes tener un adapter y este adapter necesita un arreglo( llamémosle `array`) que contiene los datos que estas mostrando(para tu caso supongo que seria un arreglo de String), entonces si quieres agregar más items al list view, lo que deberías hacer es agregar un item a ese arreglo `array` y luego notificarle al adapter que se ha cambiado tu arreglo. Para ejemplificarlo, te dejo el siguiente ejemplo.

```
public class ListViewActivity extends ListActivity {

    ArrayList<String> array =new ArrayList<String>();      
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
        array);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

}


public void addItems(String item) {
    array.add(item);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}}
```

Como puedes observar, se agrega el elemento a la lista `array.add(item);` y luego se notifica que se ha agregado un nuevo item `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`. En tu caso luego de devolver el item del segundo fragmento, debes llamar al método `addItems` para agregar tu nuevo item.

Ahora te pongo un ejemplo de comunicación entre fragments, este ejemplo lo hace mediante algo llamado callbacks e utiliza al activity como intermediario, es decir tenemos los siguiente componentes : Fragment1, Fragment 2 y un activity ( que contiene o contendrá a los dos fragments).

La idea es la siguiente:

- Debes crear la interfaz desde el fragment donde se quiere enviar información ( para tu caso seria desde el fragment 2)
- Que el padre implemente la interfaz que se ha creado en el fragment 2( en tu caso tu activity deberá implementar la interfaz que creaste en el fragment 2)
- Cuando quiera comunicarte con tu fragment1, lo que tienes que hacer es llamar a este callback con el mensaje que le quieres enviar, para tu caso seria un String.

Comparto un ejemplo de la misma documentación de android que explica paso a paso que es lo que deberías hacer:

Referencia : https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating?hl=es#java

Para tu ejemplo propuesto:

En tu unoFragment tienes el método `updateTextView`. En este método el parámetro `mensaje` es tu nuevo que estas mandando del edittext de tu dosFragment hacia el unoFragment, lo único que tienes que hacer es agregar `message` a tu arreglo es decir, con el ejemplo que te puse, algo como esto:

```
public void updateTextView(String message){
    addItems(item);
}

public void addItems(String item) {
    array.add(item);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}}
```

Con eso terminarias de agregar el item enviado de tu fragment2 :)

Comment: Hola rguzman, gracias por responder. Lo que estoy un poco perdido es como realizar la comunicación del segundo fragment con el primero. Estuve leyendo y al parecer es con bundle...ahí es donde agradeceria apoyo para como hacer desde el segundo fragment agregar item...porfavor.

Comment: He editado mi respuesta con tu consulta :)

Comment: Gracias Rguzman, mira edite la pregunta e inclui lo que he avanzado. Logro abrir desde el unoFragment  el dosFragment con un boton, pero no logro devolver el contenido de un editText al unoFragment tambien con un boton...por favor.

Comment: Lo edité nuevamente :)

Comment: Gracias RGuzman, leyendo las referencias y tu ejemplo he logrado agregar item a la lista mediante una interface en el activity que comunica los dos fragment. Muchas gracias por tu tiempo y ayuda amigo.